# Count posts published in one particular day: the lighter way

Tags: count

I would like to get just the number of posts published in one particular day. I'm using this code, but this retrieve lot of code:

```
$day = date('Ymd');
$query01 = array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => array('post', 'video', 'image', 'review'), 'm' => $day);
$mypost = get_posts($query01);
$counter = count($mypost);
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Is there a lighter way to obtain the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$wp_query->found_posts` can be used to get the number of posts. But here are arguments you can use to optimize the query and avoid useless SQL retrievals:

```
cache_results' => false, // Turns off post caching
'no_found_rows' => true, // To optimize when pagination is not required
'fields' => 'ids'  // To only retrieve IDs information, nothing else (avoid collecting all useless post data)
```

If you have more optimizing tips for simple queries, I would be happy to hear about them